# php regular expression for e mail

Tags: php, regex, input

try to make regular expression for mail but it not work

i want to remove all other special character or any char not allowed in email

so except `0-9 a-z A-Z - _ @`

every other char must be removed .

```
$pass = preg_replace ('#[^a-z0-9-_.@]+#i', '', $_GET['e']);

echo $pass ;
```

if i try  `33.php?e=frefr_-+_)(*&^%$#!@edef.fr`

i get : `"  frefr_-_ "`

and i must get : `frefr_-_@edef.fr`

and remove all other char from the email .
thank you :)

Comment: The most you should ever bother trying to validate is that it contains at least one `@` symbol. The standard governing what an email address is is so permissive that virtually anything is allowed and it's nigh-impossible to write a regular expression for it. Just send an email to it and have the user click a link to confirm that: A. It's a valid address. B. They actually want to receive email from you.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question requesting "regex" but validating emails with regex is incredibly complicated and subject to potential maintenance as internet standards change.

List of valid emails and thus complex regex needed:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Instead, I suggest you instead use the built in tools which will get updated along with PHP to save your having to do it.

> [FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
>   Remove all characters except letters, digits and !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[].

```
$filteredEmail = filter_var($fullEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

> [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)
>    Validates whether the value is a valid e-mail address.
>
> In general, this validates e-mail addresses against the syntax in RFC 822, with the exceptions that comments and whitespace folding and dotless domain names are not supported.

```
$emailValid = filter_var($fullEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

This will return the email if valid, otherwise boolean `false` which you can check against.

Answer (score 0):

i find it :P

```
$email = preg_replace ('#[^a-z0-9-_@.]+#i', '', $_GET['e']);
```

the "&" and "#" in the link was coused problem in testing .

Comment: When you're creating a URL, you have to encode special characters with `%`.

Comment: Use `urlencode()` in PHP, `encodeURIComponent()` in Javascript.

Comment: yes , i forget that in testing :)  ,btw  thank u for the edit